# Using If and Else statements for purchased orders with confirmation box

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function purchaseClicked() {
    var orders = prompt("Are you sure you want to purchase this Items?");
    if (orders != null) {
        alert('Try choosing your items again!')
    } else {
        alert('Thank you for your purchase');
        var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
        while (cartItems.hasChildNodes()) {
            cartItems.removeChild(cartItems.firstChild)
        }
        updateCartTotal()
    }
}
```

Can you please fix this.It doesn 't seem to work. I am trying to say if  button clicked and confirm box comes up saying are you sure you want to purchase if yes then box alerting thanks for purchase if not then another message says please try again and box closes

Comment: If you want to show confirmation only then you should use `confirm` instead of `prompt`. Please explain your issue in details means what is expected outcome ?

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please take some time to read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. In this case, what we would need to help you is a [Minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
function purchaseClicked() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to purchase this Items?")) {
        alert('Thank you for your purchase');
        ...
    } else {
        alert('Try choosing your items again!')
        ...
    }
}
```

PS: gussing this is what you are trying to do :)

Comment: Thanks. It made me think differently. I just removed ELSE statement.